# Верстка кнопки - a или button

Tags: html, css

1. Часто вижу что верстают кнопку при помощи ссылки то есть a>span. И
   уже их стилизируют под кнопку. Нормальная ли это практика и где
   здесь плюсы? Я же придерживаюсь стандартной button.
2. Как лучше задавать ширину и высоту кнопки, фиксированную или исходя из содержимого кнопки, тс при помощи padding'ов?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. 1 зависит от результата действия, например кнопка «следующая страница» вполне может быть ссылкой, а кнопка отправки формы — нет. 2 очевидно зависит от дизайна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На первый пункт вопроса ответ взял у Флэнагана:

> *Когда действие, выполняемое обработчиком onclick, можно классифицировать как «переход по ссылке», используйте ссылку. В
>   противном случае используйте кнопку.*

Comment: Спасибо! очень хороший ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего используется фиксированная ширина кнопки(если страница уже нарисована), а когда страница верстается как шаблон для cms или заготовка - тогда могут быть и паддинги.

Comment: для себя я отметил что лучше паддиги, сейчас верстаю один макет, там много одинаковых кнопок по стилю и "относительному" размеру.

Answer (score 0):

**1 Вопрос.**
[image: Это кнопка (button)]

[image: Это ссылки (a)]

На первом изображении 
На втором изображении 
Мысль в том, что лучше придерживаться семантики, но иногда бывают и исключения.

**2. Вопрос.** Лучше паддингами.

Вообще лучще задавать шаблон кнопки, как пример так:

```
/* Кнопка (цветная) */
.button {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  border-radius: var(--radius);
  color: var(--white);
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: border-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  max-width: fit-content; }
.button.blue {
  background-color: var(--blue);
}
.button.green {
  background-color: var(--green);
}
```